# Not able to connect my rpi to the WiFi

Tags: wifi, pi-3b+, ethernet, connection, git

I have my RPi connected to the Wi-Fi as well as the ethernet cable connected to it, but I cannot reach any websites. I am trying to clone a GitHub repository. Has anyone ever had this problem before? If so, how did you solve this?

I can't install OpenCV either. I ran the command:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-opencv -y
```

and got a message:

```
Unable to locate package python3-opencv
```

Any direction and/ or input is very appreciated. I'll keep you guys updated.

Comment: please think about your problem and about what you are asking ... asking about installing OpenCV makes no sense, you already know that you cannot connect to the internet

Comment: You have provided absolutely NO information or diagnostics. See [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697). The ABSOLUTE least is the output of `ip r`.

Comment: BTW, you can't install a binary for OpenCV. You must build it. Prepare for it to take over 1 hour.

Answer (score 2):

Please download and flash the image [Raspberry Pi OS (32-bit) Lite](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspberry-pi-os/) without any modifications. Connect the RasPi wired to your internet router and boot the RasPi with the fresh flashed image. Then do a `ping 8.8.8.8`. If it doesn't work then the problem is your network, not the RasPi.

If it works then follow [Setting up a wireless LAN via the command line](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md). If it doesn't work then you have made a typo, or the problem is your WiFi access point.